# Which Iain M Banks short stories have been adapted for radio?

Tags: short-stories, iain-m-banks, radio-play

I have been told that several Iain M Banks short stories have been adapted for radio, probably broadcast by the BBC. Hunting online all I can find is a reference to an adaptation of "The State of The Art". Wikipedia states that radio adaptations of "Espedair Street" and "The Business" have been produced but I see no reference to any other short stories. Wikipedia sometimes has gaps so I am curious to know if anyone out there has additional information or can confirm this is the only story produced.

Comment: Searching on BBC Sounds at https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?filter=programmes&q=iain+banks gives you a couple - might have to filter out short stories yourself though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BBC recorded a full cast audio of the titular work, ***[The State of the Art](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00hv1dz)*** in 2009.

A version of the urban fantasy ***[The Business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_Soundtracks)*** was recorded (and scored) by Paul Oakenfold as part of his *books-to-music* series on Galaxy FM in 1999.

An [abridgement of **The Business**](http://www.suttonelms.org.uk/NT.HTML) was also created for BBC Radio 4 in 2010, presumably to fit a book review segment.

---

Aside from this, none of his other *science fiction/fantasy* works appear to have been recorded for radio, although some of his other fiction books and short stories ([Piece](https://audiodrama.fandom.com/wiki/Piece), [The Crow Road](http://www.britishfantasysociety.org/forum/index.php?topic=25.15), [The Wasp Factory](http://efanzines.com/Banksoniain/Banksoniain01.pdf) and [Espedair Street](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Espedair_Street_(radio)), for example) have been seen.

Comment: Thank you, really was not aware the one titled Piece and had not spotted any reference to it on my own searches!

Comment: @dominicfonde - Some of these are really quite obscure. Good luck finding them to buy or download.

Comment: [Stonemouth (TV)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4274822/)

Comment: [Complicity (TV)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0188518/?ref_=nm_ov_bio_lk2)

Comment: [The Crow Road (TV)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115145/?ref_=nm_knf_t4)

Comment: [Consider Phlebas (TV - Upcoming)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8040862/?ref_=nm_knf_t1)